# How Do I Add an SVG to My Javascript .textContent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-deployment

I am simply trying to insert an exclamation SVG here, but I can't seem to do it, and I am unable to find an adequate answer on Google.

The SVG is downloaded, and contained within my project folder.

```
if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
        emailError.textContent = '(SVG Here) You need to enter an e-mail address.';
```

Comment: is `emailError` a display element such as a span, p or div? If so, have you tried something like: `emailError.innerHTML = '<img src="image.svg" /> You need to enter an e-mail address.';`

Comment: Did you tried the `<img>` html tag? Maybe you will need to convert you `svg` to `base64` and use it with thetag like:  `<img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image' src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,<!-- Base64 data -->' />`

Comment: @DavePritlove I get an error of when I submit the form the result is: 

<img src="222.svg" height="15"/> You need to enter an e-mail address.

The SVG doesn't actually display.

Comment: You can't insert SVG as text context because it is not just text. You have to use innerHTML or other options

Comment: @bigorangeduck `.innerHTML` as per my initial comment, not `.textContent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `e-mailError` is a display element in your html (span, p, div etc.) the icon and associated text can be loaded by setting the `.innerHTML` property of the element.

The use of `.textContent` will result in the markup text being displayed rather than the intended layout (as you have found)

This working snippet demonstrates the difference.

```js
const emailError=document.getElementsByClassName("emailError");

emailError[0].innerHTML = '<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.svg" /> You need to enter an e-mail address.';

emailError[1].textContent = '<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.svg" /> You need to enter an e-mail address.';
```

```css
img {
width: 40px;
aspect-ratio: 1;
}

span {
border: 1px solid black;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Example loaded using .innerHTML:</p>
<p><span class="emailError"></span></p>

<p>Example loaded using .textContent:</p>
<p><span class="emailError"></span></p>
```